# checking multiple values in between two columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying for a MySQL query to check multiple values between two columns values.
For example, for one value here is my query which works

```
SELECT column3
FROM table
WHERE (12 between minvaluecol AND maxvaluecol) AND
      id = 123;
```

I would like to check multiple values like (12,13,14,67,68) and should return the values that are in between minvaluecol and maxvaluecol columns. In this case, only 12,13,14 are in between minvaluecol and maxvaluecol columns whereas 67,68 are not.

my table looks like this,

```
id   | minvaluecol | maxvaluecol
---- | ----------- | ------------
121  | 23          |  35
123  | 10          |  20
125  | 40          |  50
```

output for id 123 should look like,

```
12  | true
13  | true
14  | true
67  | false
68  | false
```

Please help me with this query in MySQL. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you mixing integers and strings.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have updated my question with a sample table and desired resultset. Considering only numerics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Completely revamped the answer based on updated question.

As you need all the values as different rows, you need to `SELECT` all of them with `UNION` and `LEFT JOIN` it with the original table, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.val, IF(a.val BETWEEN tv.minvaluecol AND maxvaluecol, 'true', 'false') AS result
FROM (
SELECT 12 AS val
UNION 
SELECT 13 AS val
UNION 
SELECT 14 AS val
UNION 
SELECT 67 AS val
UNION 
SELECT 68 AS val) a
JOIN test_values tv
WHERE tv.id = 123;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f40b7/1/0)**.

Comment: Of course you can compare strings using `between`. It's just plain wrong when you mix integers and strings :-)

Comment: There might be some values which are not in between these columns like strings or other numbers. The above query is returning true even if one value is in between two columns. I would like to know what are all the values that are in between the columns.

Comment: @Ramya: Then switch to `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: @dnoeth, 'AND' will fail even if one value is not in between the two columns. But the query should output that 12,13,14 are in between where as 67 is not in between. Please suggest.

Comment: @Ramya: I don't get what you want, currently it just sounds quite silly.

Comment: @dnoeth, I have updated the question with my table structure and desired output. Have a look at it and let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get your result is to Insert those values into a table and then join like this:

```
SELECT value, 
   CASE WHEN value between minvaluecol AND maxvaluecol THEN 'true ELSE 'false' END
FROM table 
CROSS JOIN table_with_values
WHERE id = 123
ORDER BY value
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The values are dynamic and changes frequently. So need to see if we can achieve this without creating a table_with_values.